# jQuery selector for specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a similar table like this:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
            <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
            <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="troe"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='lat[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='long[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow">
                <input type='text' class='place' name='place[]' />
                 <span class="check"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="troe"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='lat[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='long[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow">
                <input type='text' class='place' name='place[]' />
                 <span class="check"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="troe"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='lat[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow"> <input type='text' class='lat' name='long[]' /> </td>
            <td class="trow">
                <input type='text' class='place' name='place[]' />
                 <span class="check"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

that actually looks like this picture:
see the table
[image]
 Now if I write a jQuery script to select any specific .check class (i.e. **third row-third cell-span**) and write any html message, what should be the selector?
As you know if I use `$('.check').html("Hello World");` then it prints `Hello World` in all the spans. I need to print the `Hello World` only in a specific span.
TIA.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: edited @BhargavChudasama

Comment: eloborate more like on what event you want to select third row third cell span? have you tried anything on your end

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar suppose each of the cell of that table is an input box and i want to select the span on blur() event.

Comment: actually this will not reflect the actual project i'm working on, this is just a case study.

Comment: do you want to make table fields editable on click or double click? something like https://jsfiddle.net/u7ofjprw/87/

Comment: @SophiaJose if you need more help after this question (specifically about setting html in an nth selector), please ask a new question - it keeps the existing answers matching the original question.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have edited my table, can you pls see once again?

Comment: @SophiaJose as per my comment above, please revert your question to the original and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

To select the third row, third cell, span, you could use something like this

```
$( "table tr:eq(3) .check" ).text('CONTENT');
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skvymjxa/)

---

Regarding your comment, I updated the code in [the fiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/skvymjxa/3/) to this

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.closest('tr').find('.check').text('Hello World');
})
```

What this does is when you click outside the input field (blur event), it get's the row element and searches for the `.check` element. Instead of .text, you can do whatever you want with it once it's selected.

Comment: That's great, but i need to select **.check** class on `blur()` event for any input field of that row, in that case how can I get the selector? TIA

Comment: @SophiaJose I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq(n)` (selector) or `.eq(n)` (jquery method) (both 0-based) to target a specific, index-based element, eg:

```
$(".check:eq(2)").text("hello world")
$(".check").eq(2).text("hello world")
```

```js
$(".check:eq(2)").text("hello world (2)")
$(".check").eq(1).text("hello world (1)")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </td>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's great, but i need to select **.check** class on `blur()` event for any input field of that row, in that case how can I get the selector? TIA

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `nth-child` and get third row third cell span. see below code

```js
$(function(){
  $("table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) span.check").html("Changed text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
        <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `:nth-child(2)`

```js
$(function() {
  $("tr:nth-child(2)").find('.check').html('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
    <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
    <th class="theader"> .theader </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
      <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
      <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="troe"> .trow </th>
      <td class="trow"> .trow </th>
        <td class="trow"> <span class="check"></span> </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```